# Timeline / Scheduling plugin

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to find the best option for having a timeline for scheduling multiple people or vehicles to service calls. I am working in VB.net

I found this picture but have no idea what the plugin is called.

http://www.jefbar.com/Portals/135584/images/cad%20scheduler.gif

Has anyone seen this plugin or any very similar to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend you the scheduler from DevExpress. I'm not sure if you are speaking about Winforms or ASP.NET, so I'll paste here both of them.

Winforms
https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/winforms/scheduler/

ASP.NET
https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/asp/scheduler/